# Windows application keeps crashing ntdll.dll error

Tags: windows-10, crash

I installed a fresh copy of Windows 10 and now when I run a certain adobe air application, it will crash intermittently with a Windows error.

```
*Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.14393.447, time stamp: 0x5819be95*

*Exception code: 0xc0000005*

*Fault offset: 0x000ab3b3*

*Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll**
```

This never happened on my Windows 7 install, which basically had the exact same applications installed.

I have tried reinstalling the applications and graphics/Adobe Flash drivers to no avail.

Is there any way I can find the root cause of the crashing before I attempt to roll back to Windows 7, such as from dump files etc?

Comment: Sounds like a DLL version problem. Run Dependency Walker against your Adobe app, the download the version of the DLL whcih it requires ... http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: Didn't seem to pick out anything in particular.

Comment: Is there any way to run a strack trace from the event viewer error to see what exactly triggered it?

Comment: "Didn't seem to pick out anything in particular " - do you mean that you saw no information about the DLL? if so, the app does not use it. If it did, it should give you a version number

Comment: this is a coding error in Adobe. submit it to Adobe, we can't fix it